# Looking for a contact address. Most disgusting experience with EasyJet

Tags: easyjet

Just had the most disgusting ever flight experience in over 35 years of travelling, with EasyJet. Basically a good dozen people missed their flights because of sheer incompetence of the EasyJet personnel at Venice airport.

Since I cannot find any email address or anything where to complain at EasyJet, does anyone have an address to complain that will work?

Comment: This sounds like a rant, not an objective question. I suggest you edit it a bit, even if you are upset.

Comment: You can just throw it in the trash. That has exactly the same effect as complaining to Easy Jet and is faster.

Comment: Twitter via @easyJet would be my go-to.

Comment: You could try this https://www.resolver.co.uk/companies/easyjet-complaints/contact-details

Comment: @o.m. I opened this question expecting to find a rant, but I don't think it's anywhere near long enough to qualify.

Comment: Did you miss your flight?

Answer (score 2):

EasyJet has a contact page [here](https://www.easyjet.com/en/help/contact). They have a live chat ant contact number listed there.

If your flight qualifies for EC261 compensation you can apply for it [here](https://www.easyjet.com/en/claim/eu261). The eligibility includes passengers departing from or arriving at any airport in the EU (including Iceland, Norway, or Switzerland) and whose flight delay is 3 hours or more at their final destination.